# An error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server

Tags: tfs, ssas

We are running TFS 2012 in our house for around 3 months and in particular "processing of cubes" was working fine till 14/08. At that point is just stopped to work (nothing was done on the server <- or at least I didn't found any changes yet)

What we get in the windows log looks like this:

> Detailed Message: TF221122: An error occurred running job Full
>   Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation
>   server TEAM FOUNDATION. Exception Message: Failed to Process Analysis
>   Database 'Tfs_Analysis'. (type WarehouseException) Exception Stack
>   Trace:    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ProcessOlap(AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType
>   processingType, WarehouseChanges warehouseChanges, Boolean
>   lastProcessingFailed, Boolean cubeSchemaUpdateNeeded)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.AnalysisDatabaseSyncJobExtension.RunInternal(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseJobExtension.Run(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage)

Inner Exception Details:

> Exception Message: Errors in the high-level relational engine. The
>   following exception occurred while the managed IDbConnection interface
>   was being used: . Errors in the high-level relational engine. A
>   connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID
>   of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors
>   in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension,
>   with the ID of 'Dim Team Project', Name of 'Team Project' was being
>   processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while
>   the 'ProjectNodeSk' attribute of the 'Team Project' dimension from the
>   'Tfs_Analysis' database was being processed. Internal error: The
>   operation terminated unsuccessfully. Errors in the high-level
>   relational engine. The following exception occurred while the managed
>   IDbConnection interface was being used: . Errors in the high-level
>   relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source
>   with the DataSourceID of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of
>   'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error
>   occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Team Project', Name
>   of 'Team Project' was being processed. Errors in the OLAP storage
>   engine: An error occurred while the 'Project Node Type' attribute of
>   the 'Team Project' dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis' database was
>   being processed. Errors in the high-level relational engine. The
>   following exception occurred while the managed IDbConnection interface
>   was being used: . Errors in the high-level relational engine. A
>   connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID
>   of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors
>   in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension,
>   with the ID of 'Dim Team Project', Name of 'Team Project' was being
>   processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while
>   the 'Is Deleted' attribute of the 'Team Project' dimension from the
>   'Tfs_Analysis' database was being processed. Errors in the high-level
>   relational engine. The following exception occurred while the managed
>   IDbConnection interface was being used: . Errors in the high-level
>   relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source
>   with the DataSourceID of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of
>   'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error
>   occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Team Project', Name
>   of 'Team Project' was being processed. Errors in the OLAP storage
>   engine: An error occurred while the 'Project Node Name' attribute of
>   the 'Team Project' dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis' database was
>   being processed. Errors in the high-level relational engine. The
>   following exception occurred while the managed IDbConnection interface
>   was being used: . Errors in the high-level relational engine. A
>   connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID
>   of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors
>   in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension,
>   with the ID of 'Dim Team Project', Name of 'Team Project' was being
>   processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while
>   the 'Project Path' attribute of the 'Team Project' dimension from the
>   'Tfs_Analysis' database was being processed. Server: The current
>   operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction
>   failed.
>
> Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding', referring to ID(s)
>   'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, FactCurrentWorkItem', has been specified
>   but has not been used. Warning: Parser: Out of line object 'Binding',
>   referring to ID(s) 'Tfs_Analysis, Team System, FactWorkItemHistory',
>   has been specified but has not been used.

...

so far :
- I've tried to force full processing of the cube, thru instruction from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237(v=vs.100).aspx 
- I've tried to "rebuild reporting" from "TFS admin console"->"Application tire"->"Reporting"->"Start rebuild:
- finally I've also tried just to process directly from "SQL Managment studio" : Tfs_analysie->Process
- I've checked c:\olap\logs\msmdsrv file and I didn't found any errors there

beside that we also tried to:
- restart server
- restart just services

nothing of above helped.

Our TFS is :
- hosted on one machine 
- updated to "Update 3" (right after setting it up)
- we use three different domain account to host TFS services, SQL, reporting services <- but nothing get changed in names/password of those account since installation. I've also verified that those accounts have access to proper databases.

Does anyone have similar problem ? Any ideas are really welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think the core error is `A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'` Check the data source settings, especially the connection string. Typical reasons are connection protocol settings wrong so that the protocol configured for Analysis Services is not configured for the relational engine, firewall or authentication issues.

Comment: I found solution to that problem. My cube was broken and it has to be regenerated by TFS. Solution was to remove it and force recreation of it from Team fundation administrator console.

Comment: @MariuszGorzoch I appear to be in the same situation. can you elaborate a bit on how you fixed this please?

Comment: @timB33 — Did you find it? It looks like it's on the Reporting node... **Start Rebuild**.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue (also TFS2012).  Restarting the Analysis Service did the trick for me this time.  Also check the account/password "Tfs_AnalysisDataSource" is using by clicking "Properties" in SQL Server Management Studio.  I had a similar issue a while back when the passwords changed.